# Accessing Event Grid management through Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've run into a problem of not having the slightest idea how to authenticate with my back-end service in order to create a new subscription in a event grip topic using REST API. I've been stuck here for quite a while now, could anyone give m some pointers?

I managed to create the subscription using my own user access token, so everything regarding creation logic works. The only problem is authentication/authorization.

Comment: Do you mean to get access token to use this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/subscription/createorupdate)?

Comment: Yep, that's the way I'd prefer, unless there are other, more recommended, ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample about getting the access token with c#:

```
var clientId = "your-application-id";
var clientSecret = "client-Secret";
var tenantId = "your-tenant-id";
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId);
var accessToken = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result.AccessToken;

Console.WriteLine(accessToken);
```

Then refer to this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56882357/13308381) for calling REST API with HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out and let you know how it went. =)

Comment: Hmm, I get the token, but it still returns 401.

Just now saw the error message, continuing to investigate

Comment: The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant.

Comment: If I authenticate using Azure CLI, I manage to get the valid token. If I do it in code - I get the error specified above. 

Puid exist in the token acquired by Azure CLI.

Comment: Yep, managed to get it working with this snippet, Thanks! Can you link me to the documentation you found it in?

Comment: Yes! I refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40504150/13308381).